# Rotate a UI Button in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, button, rotation

Quick and hopefully obvious question.

I have a progmatically created button in my iPhone app that I wish to rotate 45 degrees clockwise, named buttonuq , how can I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a transformation like :

```
yourButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(45.0*M_PI/180.0);
```

Good Luck !

Comment: thanks, I'd been given the impression this only worked for image objects.

Comment: Indeed - upon trying I receive this message    error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'setTransform:'

Comment: My fault, I edited with the good function ( CGAffineTransformMakeRotation )

Comment: Thanking you - I'll not be programming tonight but shall explore this fully once I get the opportunity (work comittments I'm afraid to say!)

Comment: Just had another look at this and noticed while the rotation works, it automagically sticks the button in the top left corner of my screen - any ideas? It works fine other than that (iPhone iOS 4.1 on a 3GS)

Comment: On applying same code m getting this error: request for member 'transform' in something not a structure or union.  Pls suggest wat can i do for it ?

Comment: `(45.0*M_PI/180.0)` can also be written as `(M_PI/4)`